# Instance Variable Usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller. In the controller I have two methods. I would like a variable whose value is set in method 1 to be accessible in method 2. Could I use an instance variable to achieve this?

Comment: I dont see why the value should be reset if all you are doing is printing from the second method.

Comment: So normally I would have no issues accessing an instance variable set in one method in another method of the same class?

Comment: If so, would there be a setting in the application controller that could be causing me to lose the value?

Comment: are you accessing method 1 and method 2 from the same request? same thread? Or are you setting the instance variable on 1 page, and trying to read it from another?

Comment: setting it on one page and trying to read it from another

Comment: would the solution be  session variable then? thanks for your help. it's much appreciated.

Comment: so the controller/action is localhost:3000/user/login
in that controller/action I have set an instance variable

when ..../user/logout is called I would like to have access to that same instance variable or information or however I have to encapsulate it.

Comment: It would be better if you can show your code for the Controller.

Comment: yes you will need to throw it in the session.  Since if you set it in the instance, when you come back to that controller it is a new request. throw it in the session and you can pull it out on another page.

Comment: cool. When would a session variable be reset? I assume they are stored in the users cookies or...?

I recognize that they could be reset with reset_session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use an instance variable for this as long as everything is happening in a single request.

So something like this:

```
class PancakesController < ApplicationController
  def where_is
    @house = Pancake.find(params[:id])
    render :json => mangle, :status => :ok
  end

private

  def mangle
    @house
  end
end
```

will work as expected. However, this sort of thing:

```
class PancakesController < ApplicationController
  def where_is
    @house = Pancake.find(params[:id])
    #...
  end

  def mangle
    if(@house)
      #...
    end
    #...
  end
end
```

won't work if `where_is` and `mangle` are called in difference requests.

Remember that the lifetime of a controller instance is a single request.

Comment: Gotcha. That last line is essential. I needed reminded of that. What is the lifetime of a session variable?

Comment: @Drew: Session values will last until the session expires or the person logs out; you can use the session to pass things between controller calls but you usually don't want anything too big in the session and you still have to be prepared for it to disappear (but it should be okay for short term purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an instance variable to achieve that.